# Javascript hide div and show another div with simple countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there any way to hide a div and show another div with javascript?

for example:

```
<div id="box1"></div>

<div id="box2"></div>
```

there's 2 divs. first, div id box2 is hidden and i need countdown timer for like 10 seconds showing on div id box1 and when countdown 10 seconds is over then hide div id box1 and show box2

Thanks for who answers my question.

Comment: It looks like you want a content slider. Cycle 2 is a good pre-built option. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Comment: no, not content slider. i just want it like, when page loaded, div id box1 must be display:block; what i mean showing on the page and simple countdown on it for like 10 seconds. and when 10 seconds is over then hide div id box1 and show div id box2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want a pure Javascript version?

http://plnkr.co/edit/55h5cmxOAZeNTGbKzedA?p=preview

```
setInterval(function thing() {

  var b1 = document.getElementById('box1');
  var b2 = document.getElementById('box2');

  if(b1['style'].display == 'none') {
    b1['style'].display = 'block';
    b2['style'].display = 'none';
  } else {
    b1['style'].display = 'none';
    b2['style'].display = 'block';
  }

}, 10000);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it's not showing any countdown timer on div id box1 instead of value number 1

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  It waits 10 seconds then switches which div it is showing.  Are you saying you actually want to see the countdown in the div?

Comment: sorry yes. i mean i want to see that 10 seconds countdown timer in the div

Comment: Well, I still don't know exactly what you want, you show be able to work it out yourself from here: http://plnkr.co/edit/FwKPRB9EAF3B2jwKUpdp?p=preview

Comment: that's what i need exactly thanks a lot. but there's a little problem that, it's repeating that 10 seconds again and again. can you please just make it once time 10 seconds finished and div2 showed up and it must keep it like that. it should not hide the div again and start 10 seconds again etc